# How to solve "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel" in a single call of a multi threaded app?

Tags: c#, security, certificate

I am writing a network app, and I'm getting "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel" exception.

From the documents I've researched, I gathered that this can be solved through

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    delegate(
        object sender,
        X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    };
```

While this works, to me it seems like a really bad idea. I want to skip certificate check only when I know what I'm doing only for the web call that I'm doing, and I don't want to suspend certificate checking altogether.

Is there a localized way to suspend certificate verification for a single HttpWebRequest without having to affect all the other web calls that the application is doing at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the `sender` object which probably is a proxy instance and from that you should be able to find out if you need to intervene.

Also you may examine the certificate and other parameters to decide if it is valid.